# Create object for every property through Proxy

Tags: vue.js

I'm builiding a local storage for my data for a Vue + Laravel SPA app.

The storage looks as such:

```
const Storage =
{
    handler:
    {
        get: function(o, prop)
        {
            return localStorage.getItem('storage.data.' + prop)
        },
        set: function(o, prop, value)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('storage.data.' + prop, value)
        }
    }
}
```

`Vue.prototype.$storage = new Proxy(Storage, Storage.handler)`

Fairly simple, I would say.

The issue I'm having is, I want the code below to create all neccessary objects as it goes through:

```
this.$storage.auth.token.kohen = 'test'
```

To put more bluntly, I want objects `auth` and `token` to be created when I set `kohen`, so I don't have to do:

```
this.$storage.auth = {}
this.$storage.auth.token = {}
```

The problem with that is, it runs get on `auth` first - which also returns `undefined`.

Comment: `$storage.auth.token.kohen` is not a property of `$storage` however `$storage.auth` is. Try to print what `prop` is to fully understand how the proxy works

Comment: You can also have a look at this solution on [How to use javascript proxy for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41300128/7316365)

Comment: @Vivick So, I should use proxies for nested objects aswell and just keep track of a parent?