# JS proxy SET function does not get triggered when object property value gets changed

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this example:

```js
let proxyHandler = {
   set(obj, prop, value) {
      console.log("triggered");
   }
};

let p = new Proxy({
   person: {
      name: "Max"
   },
   age: 20,
}, proxyHandler);

p.age = 22;
p.person.name = "Tom";

console.log(p.person);
```

As you can see the setter got triggerd for the primitive type variable but not for the reference type (object).

The setter gets only triggered if i override the whole object, but i need to detect if changes happend inside of it.

Is it possible to trigger the setter no matter how deeply nested the property is? Same for arrays.

Comment: [How to use javascript proxy for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299642/how-to-use-javascript-proxy-for-nested-objects)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev i will take a look